# OCaml string and Coq string (Extraction from Coq to OCaml)

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I used the extraction from Coq to OCaml, where I have type `Z`, `N`, `positive`

I don't use to extract it in `int` of OCaml.

Then the type I have after the extraction is:

```
type positive =
| Coq_xI of positive
| Coq_xO of positive
| Coq_xH

type coq_N =
| N0
| Npos of positive

type coq_Z =
| Z0
| Zpos of positive
| Zneg of positive
```

I have a program in OCaml where some functions using the OCaml type `string`.

In my OCaml program, I need to write some functions convert the type: `string -> coq_N`, `string -> coq_Z`, `string -> positive`

I tried to write the functions in Coq and then used the extraction to get the OCaml type but Coq `string` is different from OCaml `string`.

For instance:

```
open Ascii
open BinNums
open Datatypes

type string =
| EmptyString
| String of ascii * string

let string_of_coqN (s: string): coq_N =
  match s with
    | EmptyString -> N0
    | String (a, _) -> (coq_N_of_ascii a);;
```

where `coq_N_of_ascii` is the extraction from `coq` function `N_of_ascii`.

When I applied the function `string_of_coqN`, for instance:

```
let test (x: string) = string_of_N x;;
```

I got the complain that

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         String0.string
```

Could you please help me to find a way to write the convert functions : `string -> coq_N`, `string -> coq_Z` and `string -> positive`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For strings, the easiest thing to do is probably to import the standard library module `ExtrOcamlString` in your extraction file, which will cause Coq to extract them as a `char list` in OCaml. You can then convert between `char list` and native `string`s with custom code. Have a look for instance at file `lib/Camlcoq.v` in the [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr) distribution, functions `camlstring_of_coqstring` and `coqstring_of_camlstring`.